# After upgrade to 22.04: cifs-mount des no longer work

Tags: upgrade, mount, 22.04, samba, cifs

I had setup a cifs mount point under Ubuntu 20.04 LTS. It does no longer work after upgrade to 22.04 LTS.

Giving the following mount command from the shell

```
sudo mount -t cifs  //xxx.yyy.zzz.www/directory /mymountpoint -o sec=ntlm,credentials=/home/username/.qnap/credentials.txt,rw,uid=1001,gid=1001,vers=1.0
```

I get the error message on the terminal:

```
mount error(22): Invalid argument
```

Refer to the mount.cifs(8) manual page (e.g. man mount.cifs) and kernel log messages (dmesg)

and the `dmesg` log gives me the following line

```
Use of the less secure dialect vers=1.0 is not recommended unless required for access to very old servers
```

`man mount.cifs` does not give me anything of real help, as far as I can see all used options and their values are still allowed.

Comment: remove `sec=ntlm`

Comment: Thanks, that works.